# How to read "not 4 > 2 and 2 < 3" in python?

Tags: python

How to use "not" and "and" with comparison operators? I have never seen them before? I thought you only use "not" and "and" in a loop or under some if statements? Are there any more examples of this? What is this called?

Anyway why is not 4 > 2 and 2 < 3, false?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is down to [Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and the general [rules of statement logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference):

```
  (not 4 > 2) and 2 < 3
#      +++++ 
#      True 
# +++++++++++     +++++
#   False         True
# +++++++++++++++++++++
#         False
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's down to operator precedence, because there isn't an order of operations that would give true.

Comment: :P `(not 4 > 2 and 2) < 3`

Comment: good point, I was assuming at least consistent precedence!

Comment: This is of course a ridiculous reading, but statement is meant in general. The evaluation of such a logcial expression  depends on those two aspects.